# Ошибка получение данных с модели Magento

Tags: php, magento

Проблема с получением данных с Модели (Magento Full Release - ver 1.9.2.4).

Получаю модель в action контроллера:

```
$news = Mage::getModel('dev_news/news')->getCollection();
```

Потом чтоб получить `id` делаю:

Потом чтоб получить id делаю:

```
foreach ($news as $item) {
            echo  $item->getId()
        }
```

Pезультат:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function order() on null in /home/vitaliy/hosts/module.dev/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php:506 Stack trace: #0
```

**Как это профиксить ?** Не могу найти ответа.

файл `/etc/conf.xml`

```
<global>
        <models>
            <vitaliydev_news>
                <class>VitaliyDev_News_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>vitaliydev_news_resource</resourceModel>
            </vitaliydev_news>
            <vitaliydev_news_resource>
                <class>VitaliyDev_News_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <news>
                        <table>news</table>
                    </news>
                </entities>
            </vitaliydev_news_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <vitaliydev_news_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>VitaliyDev_News</module>
                </setup>
            </vitaliydev_news_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
```

**Model/News.php**

```
class VitaliyDev_News_Model_News extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('vitaliydev_news/news');
    }

}
```

**Model/Resource/News.php**

```
<?php

class VitaliyDev_News_Model_Resource_News extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{


    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vitaliydev_news/news','news_id');
    }
}
```

**Model/Resource/News/Collection.php**

```
<?php

class VitaliyDev_News_Model_Resource_News_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('vitaliydev_news/news');
    }


}
```

Comment: приведите файлы  модели, ресурс модели и коллекции. Похоже на то что у вас инициализация колекции неправильна.

Comment: @Naumov, вопрос отредактировал. Модели и ресурсы элементарные но все равно не  получается почему то. Очень нужна подсказка, потому что не понимаю в чем дело (

Comment: так метод `__construct` не отрабатывает инициализацию проводят в методе `_construct` который протектед и не являеться магическим методом. для примера можешь сдесь посмотреть как http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Comment: @Naumov, спасибо ) помогло